# Get all data from two Firebase database tables

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tables in firebase database.

```
Table A :       Table B:

a               a  2 pic
b               b  3 pic
c
d               d  1 pic
e
```

Result shows as :

```
a  2 pic
b  3 pic
d  1 pic
```

I need result as :

```
a  2 pic
b  3 pic
c  0 pic
d  1 pic
e  0 pic
```

I am unable How I will write the query.

I write the query as if **a** from Table A, equals **a** in Table B, then **a** will show with 2 pic. In this way, **a,b and d** shows. But **c and e** are not showing as **c and e** not equal in Table B. I want to show **c and e with 0 pictures**.

What I have tried:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ListType>();
            list.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ListType listType = ds.getValue(ListType.class);
                final String listname = listType.getName();
                
                databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                           if (postSnapshot.getKey().equals(listname)) {
                                String count = String.valueOf(postSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                                ListType listTypee = new ListType(listname, count);
                                list.add(listTypee);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                           }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @fantaghirocco I need data from Firebase Real time database

Comment: so your question is basically "how to perform a left join with firebase-etc"?

Comment: @fantaghirocco I fail how I will write the query to get all data in the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now looping over all nodes in table B, and adding their counts to the list. But since C and E are not in table B, they'll never show up in the list.

I'd actually invert the logic, and:

1. Loop over the results of reading table A
2. Check if there are nodes for that in table B
3. Add either the number of nodes or 0

In code that'd be something like:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list = new ArrayList<ListType>();
        list.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ListType listType = ds.getValue(ListType.class);
            final String listname = listType.getName();
            
            databaseReference1.child(listname).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot bSnapshot) {
                    String count = String.valueOf(bSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    ListType listTypee = new ListType(listname, count);
                    list.add(listTypee);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                }
            });
        }
```

Note that the individual listeners inside the loop are not nearly as slow as you may think, since Firebase [pipelines the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: I achieved the required result from your answer. Thank You Sir. You are really life saver.